# Argsort DataFrame according to columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

| userId | column_1 | column_2 | column_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4.959 | 3.231 | 1.2356 |
| B | 0.632 | 0.963 | 2.4556 |
| C | 3.234 | 7.445 | 5.3435 |
| D | 1.454 | 0.343 | 2.2343 |

I would like to argsort w.r.t columns from the previous one:

| userId | first | second | third |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | column_3 | column_2 | column_1 |
| B | column_1 | column_2 | column_3 |
| C | column_1 | column_3 | column_2 |
| D | column_2 | column_1 | column_3 |

Comment: it seems that he is sorting rows, and instead of numbers he is printing the column name

Comment: Basically I would like to order the values for each user. For user A, the column with the lowest value is 'column_3, the second column is 'column_2' and the column with the highest value is 'column_1'.

Comment: @Craig but how you insert column name in it?

Comment: with pleasue, thanks for the awesome answer! makes me smart too...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) over axis 1. Then convert `df.columns` to *numpy* array using [`pd.Index.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_numpy.html) and use *numpy indexing*.

```
df = df.set_index('userId') # If userId is not index already.
idx = df.values.argsort(axis=1)
out = pd.DataFrame(df.columns.to_numpy()[idx], index=df.index)

               0         1         2
userId
A       column_3  column_2  column_1
B       column_1  column_2  column_3
C       column_1  column_3  column_2
D       column_2  column_1  column_3
```

Comment: `df.columns.to_numpy()[np.argsort(df)]` after set index should also work :-)

Answer (score 2):

another method would be be to use `stack()` with `sort_values()` and `map` to set your custom colum headings.

```
mapper_ = {1 : 'first', 2 : 'second', 3 : 'third', 4 : 'fourth'}
s = (df.set_index('userId').stack().sort_values().groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1).map(mapper_)

s.reset_index(1).set_index(0,append=True).unstack(0)




        level_1                    
0          first    second     third
userId                              
A       column_3  column_2  column_1
B       column_1  column_2  column_3
C       column_1  column_3  column_2
D       column_2  column_1  column_3
```